# Rendering a like/unlike button in rails with jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using jquery to render a like button on a story. I have two models `story` and `like`

Here's the likes controller code:

```
 def create
    @like = Like.new(params[:like])
    @story = Story.find(params[:story])
    @like.story = @story

    if @like.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @like = Like.find(params[:id])
    #@story = @like.story
    @like.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to stories_url }
      format.js
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

This is the button partial (stories/like_button):

```
<% unless user_likes_story?(@story, current_user) %>
    <%= button_to 'like', "/likes?story=#{@story.id}", :id => 'like_button', :remote => true %>
<% else %>
    <%= button_to 'liked', @liked, :class => 'like_button unlike', :id => 'unlike_button', :remote => true, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that my create.js.erb, when rendering the 'unlike' button, doesn't properly load the @liked instance variable, because it's being set in the #show action of the stories controller *before* the user has liked the story, so I can't figure out how or where to set it so the JS will render the unlike properly. I'm probably making this harder than it has to be, but...

create.js.erb

```
$('.button_to').replaceWith('<%=j render 'stories/like_button' %>');
$('#story_likes_count').replaceWith('<%=j render 'stories/likes_count' %>');
```

Here's how I tried setting @liked, in stories#show

```
def show
    @like = Like.new
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    if current_user
      @liked = Like.find_by_user_id_and_story_id(current_user,@story)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @story }
    end
  end
```

Any idea how to do this properly? Should I just move the partial out of the stories folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple. In the controller, doing this:

```
 format.js {@liked = @like}
```

Passes the variable and makes it available to the partial when it's rendered.